# Terraform Route53 Data

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, devops, cloudflare, infrastructure-as-code

I'm writing terraform modules for CloudFlare resources with nameserver options. In my case if a user set the route53 nameserver, module will set a record to the cloudflare as a NS Record, otherwise user NameServers setting as a record to the CloudFlare

```
locals {
  ns = "${var.use_route53_ns_record == true ? length(data.aws_route53_zone.main.name_servers) : length(var.name_servers)}"
}

resource "cloudflare_record" "ns" {
  count  = "${local.ns}"
  domain = "${var.domain}"
  name   = "${var.domain}"
  value  = "${var.use_route53_ns_record == true ? data.aws_route53_zone.main.name_servers[count.index]:var.name_servers[count.index]}"
  type   = "NS"
  ttl    = 1
}

data "aws_route53_zone" "main" {
  name = "${var.domain}."
}
```

When I ran this module, it giving an error show as below .

> Resource 'data.aws_route53_zone.main' not found for variable 'data.aws_route53_zone.main.name_servers'

How I can set the variables as a conditional?

Thanks please help !

Comment: Is that your exact code? Adding the missing variable definitions for me (and removing the `cloudflare_record` resource for now) and running that works fine for me.

Comment: Code is valid but  in my case i wanna set the ns record coming from user or route53 nameservers